# CSS attr() for integers: What is a good way to solve this?

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries, attr

PHP Template:

```
  <div 
class="el" 
data-spacetop="<?php echo $spacetop; ?>" 
data-spaceleft="<?php echo $spaceleft; ?>" 
data-spacetopmobile="<?php echo $spacetopmobile; ?>" 
data-spaceleftmobile="<?php echo $spaceleftmobile; ?>"></div>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="el" data-spacetop="228" data-spaceleft="876" data-spacetopmobile="90" data-spaceleftmobile="20"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .el {
        padding-top: attr(data-spacetop) px;
        padding-left: attr(data-spaceleft) px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .el {
        padding-top: attr(data-spacetopmobile) px;
        padding-left: attr(data-spaceleftmobile) px;
    }
}
```

If this would work it would be just wonderful. Unfortunatly it does not, although a W3C draft has been around for a long time now (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr).

How would you solve this problem? Unfortunatly inline media queries are not supported, too.

Comment: i guess you could use Javascript to do this, detecting window size and applying inline styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to support modern browser you could use the new shining `CSS` [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) instead of `data-attributes` and `attr()`

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJWNrj)

---

**Markup**

```
<div class="el" 
style="
   --spacetop:40px;
   --spaceleft:20px;
   --spacetopmobile:10px;
   --spaceleftmobile:5px
"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.el {
  border: 1px #bc9 dashed;
  padding-top: var(--spacetop);
  padding-left: var(--spaceleft);
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .el {
    padding-top: var(--spacetopmobile);
    padding-left: var(--spaceleftmobile);
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not CSS variable instead of custom properties ?

Comment: well .. maybe am used to the french words :) and doing a systematique transalation :/

Comment: Awesome idea! Its just IE11 which is not supported right?

Comment: nice CSS only solution! wish the support for this was better; no internet explorer support, only edge (15)

Comment: well am not totally wrong, they are also called variable :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 1):

This syntaxs is correct :

```
padding-top: attr(data-spacetop px);
```

and

```
padding-top: attr(data-spacetop px,fallback);
```

but use this property in the two methods above don't support with major browsers.